# Mistake in Taylor expansion?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Given: The first derivative of $\tan x$ is $1/\cos^2 x$

So the derivative of $\tan x$ when $x=0$ should be $1$. This derivative times $x$ should be a term in the Taylor expansion (the term then being $x$).

However, in the answer it says that expansion is $1 - x^3/3\cdots$. Where did the $x$ go?

Comment: It had a hangover and the $1$ covered for it, so the boss doesn't notice. It should be $x + \frac{x^3}{3} + \dotsc$.

Comment: Taylor expansions never lie...

Answer (score 1):

$$
f(x) = \tan(x)
$$

The third order Taylor series at zero is:
$$
f(x)\approx f(0) + f'(0)x + f''(0)\frac{x^2}{2} + f'''(0)\frac{x^3}{6}
$$

You can calculate that
$$
f(0) = \tan(0) = 0
$$
$$
f'(0) = \sec^2(0) = 1
$$
$$
f''(0) = \frac{8\sin(0)}{3\cos(0)+\cos(3\cdot0)} = 0
$$
$$
f'''(0) = (4\sin^2(0)+2)\sec^4(0) = 2
$$
Plugging into the expansion, we get
$$
f(x)\approx x + \frac{x^3}{3}
$$

That's the correct expansion, the one "in the answer" you stated is incorrect.